# MongoDB shard removal taking too long

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I had set up a 9-node MongoDB shard cluster.  I need to remove one of the nodes,  so I invoked the:

```
mongos> db.runCommand( { removeShard: "clustnode9:27017" } )
```

Keep in mind my dataset contains about 25 million rows of data so approximately 2.7m rows per node.

For some reason the drain operation is taking a very long time.  I can see that it's moving forward, every half an hour or so, if I invoke:

```
mongos> db.collection.getShardDistribution()
```

I can see that my 9th shard is draining,  it goes from 8.34% to 8.33%, etc... But it's taking such a long time.    Additionally,  I actually have a need to remove not just this one shard but 3 additional shards,  but MongoDB will not allow me to remove more than one shard at any given time,   so I am just concerned that the removal operation is taking such a long time and looking for ways to speed up the drainage...

Comment: Where is the percentage complete number coming from? What output do you get when you rerun the removeShard command targeting the same shard?

Comment: %completed was coming from  db.collection.getShardDistribution()

Comment: What does rerunning removeShard on the draining shard produce?

Comment: returns "msg" : "draining ongoing".

Comment: The task completed, took a few hours--

Comment: OK. It's normal for it to take a while. It uses the balancer process which is designed to lurk in the background and not impact normal operations too much.

Comment: Well, I would disagree: during draining/rebalancing,  when I ran an explain() on my query,  instead of taking an average of 4 seconds to complete during normal processing, it was taking ~ 5 minutes to complete, about 10x slower.  But I understand that removing a shard is not something one does during normal (production) hours, so I guess I can live with that...